# Bevel modifer troubles

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface, bevel

I'm teaching myself how to model in Blender and struggling a bit with the bevel modifier. Basically I want to round off the outer edge of the bill of my hat. I expected this to be pretty simple but it just isn't working how I thought it should.

Can you help me understand why the modifier is behaving this way?

Image 1: At first the modifier doesn't seem to do anything. This is how it looks with the offest set to .2" and nothing else changed.

[image]

Image 2: If I turn off "Clamp Overlap", the modifier starts to affect the edge, but it's also creating artifacts around the edge and striations across the surface of the bill.

[image]

Image 3: This is how everything looks if I turn off my subsurf modifier. Ideally I only want the bevel to affect the outer edge of the bill. Not sure how to achieve that.

[image]

Image 4: I suspect this is the root of the problem. In order to create the bill, I extruded the green edge and repositioned the vertices in order to create the pink edge. I've noticed that these edges are connected on either side by an edge, but they don't actually form a contiguous edge loop. Could that be the reason for my troubles?

[image]

**Edit:** Added the images below in reference to the advice from @jailton_so.

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to change the **Limit Method** to **Angle**. this tells to bevel modifier to bevel only edges where the adjacent faces form an angle smaller than the defined threshold.

Comment: or select only edges that you want to bevel and (in the N panel->item)set the **Main Bevel Weigth** to 1 and in the bevel modifier set the **Limit Method** to **Weigth**

Comment: @jailton_so Thanks for responding! Both of those methods helped considerably, but I'm still getting artifacts at either vertex where the edge loop breaks. See the 5th and 6th images added above - when I try to select the edge loop, the area between those two vertices isn't included. – Swell Toad 6 mins ago

Comment: @jailton_so I also have to keep "Clamp Overlap" turned off for the bevel to take effect.

Comment: The artifacts of bevel are generated by edges intersection and is directly related to topology of your mesh, "Clamp Overlap" only prevent this intersection from occurring by blocking edges that overlap. see this video [How to fix artifacts in Blender](https://youtu.be/0T3QdLJOBF8?t=109) at 1: 49min he explains it and at 3:33min he show a way to fix this. If it didn't help, can you send me this .blend file? I can try to fix it and show you how I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Blender modifiers are applied one by one in that order, which they are placed from highest to lowest.

Try moving them with arrows up and down on the right of their bars.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, that doesn't seem to help. Thanks for your input.